# Xamaring Windows 8.1 Custom Rendered convert hex to Brush?

Tags: c#, xamarin, renderer

I am trying to follow Custom rendered process as defined here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/

I am trying to do the windows one, I am just running the windows one not the windows phone. But I cant figure out how to convert a hex colour into the required windows **SolidColorBrush**

How do i do this. I getting rather confused with the different dlls as Color exists in the portable class library too, but is not compatible.

If someone could test this and show me a working copy that would really be appreciated. Am I missing a reference?

```
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Hello.Renderer;
using Hello.Windows.Renderer;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace Hello.Windows.Renderer
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new ColorConverter().Convert("#FF6A00", null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [this converter](https://blog.kulman.sk/converting-hex-color-to-solidcolorbrush/):

```
public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(
        Color.FromArgb(
            255,
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
            Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16)
        )
    );
}
```